# Ansatz for defocusing NLS equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics

I am interested in finding a solution of the NLS equation (defocusing):
$$i \partial_t u = -\frac 12 u_{xx} + |u|^2 u$$
I hope to find a solution that is somewhat similar to that of the NLS equation (focusing):
$$i \partial_t u = -\frac 12 u_{xx} - |u|^2 u$$
I'll outline the procedure for this focusing case here--

- We may consider a solution of the form $u = v(x) e^{it}$ where $v(x) \in \mathbb R$. Plugging this in, we arrive at the ODE for $v$:
  $$-v = -\frac 12 v'' - v^3$$
  Which we can rewrite as:
  $$\frac 12 \left((v')^2\right)' = v'\partial_v (v^2 - \frac 12 v^4)$$
  Integrating both sides (and using B.C. vanishing at $\pm \infty$), we arrive at:
  $$\frac{dv}{dx} = \pm\sqrt{2 v^2 - v^4} $$
  Rewriting, we have:
  $$\int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{2v^2 - v^4}}= -\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-2 v^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}} = \pm x + c_0$$
  For a positive soliton centered at the origin, we then have:
  $$v(x) = \sqrt{2}\operatorname{sech}(\sqrt{2}\cdot x)$$

Now, going back to the defocusing case, if we likewise propose an ansatz of the form $u = v(x) e^{it}$ where $v(x)$ vanishes at $\pm \infty$, we have $v(x)$ solves the ODE:
$$v + v^3= \frac 12 v''$$
But multiplying both sides by $v$ and integrating on $\mathbb R$, we have:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} v^2 + v^4 + \frac 12 v'^2 dx = 0 \implies v(x) = 0$$
Hence, for this case, there is no such non-trivial solution of this ODE if $v$ is real.

Now, my question is this: is there an alternative ansatz I can use here for the defocusing case that would yield an analogous result to the focusing case? Indeed, if we try:
$v(x) = i \sqrt{2} \operatorname{sech}(\sqrt{2} \cdot x)$ this solves the ODE, but it fails for the ansatz (it is not real, so the $ | \cdot |^2$ term causes issues).

Comment: The ODE for $v$ you have written assumes $v$ is real. Following through the substitution allowing $v$ to be complex yields instead:

$
v+|v|^2v=v''/2
$

It does not look like $v(x)=i\sqrt{2}\operatorname{sech}(\sqrt{2}x)$ satisfies this ODE.

Comment: That's correct -- we would need the ODE you have written, so my point was such a $v$ doesn't actually work. Indeed, the ODE in this case is difficult to work with, so this ansatz doesn't work well.

Comment: Okay- are you looking specifically for a real $v$ solution? If so, I think (following your analysis) that the boundary conditions are too strict to allow this. If you allow complex $v$ then the resulting ODE may be transformed via $v(x)=R(x)e^{i\phi(x)}$ to an ODE involving $R$ alone. I am, however, unsure if that is a fruitful direction

Comment: I suggest the "first integral method".  See https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82439901.pdf

Comment: Your ansatz doesn't work because in it you have assumed that the frequency $\omega$ has positive unit value. Leave the frequency arbitrary, then the sign of it gives you some freedom in the ODE. Letting $u = e^{i \omega t} v(x)$ you would find in the defocusing case 
\begin{align}
- \omega v &= - \frac{1}{2} v'' + v^{3} \\
\implies - \frac{\omega}{2} v^{2} &= - \frac{1}{2} v'^{2} + \frac{1}{4} v^{4}
\end{align}
where the integration constant vanishes. If $\omega < 0$ then the ODE still has non-trivial solutions. This is just a specific choice of a travelling wave ansatz.

Comment: @F.Wright
This looks great. Thank you very much.

I do however, believe the solution they have at the bottom of this paper may have a typo. For instance, if we set $\alpha = 0$, the spatial part is $\operatorname{tanh}( \cdot)$ which does not vanish at $\pm \infty$, so it is not a soliton solution like they say. I'll look into it further.

Comment: @mattos Thank you for this idea. I tried it, and I end up with $v(x) = \sqrt{2 \omega} i \operatorname{sech}( \sqrt{\omega} x)$ -- hence I need to find an $\omega$ that makes this function real and also vanish at $\pm \infty$. Is this doable?

Comment: A non-trivial solution exists iff $\omega < 0 := - \lambda^{2}$.